# Need to run suite.xml through Main.class

Tags: java, testng

**NOTE:** I found a solution. I've moved my Main.class from src/main/java to src/test/java where all my test classes are.
Still, how can I reference classes that are in different folders (src and test)?

I want to run my Tests Suite (.xml) through the Main.class. I can run it directly by right clicking the .xml inside eclipse and choosing "Run as -> TestNG" but when I try running it through main it will throw an error "Cannot find class in classpath: app.tva.tests.LoginTest".

This is what I have on my Main.class:

```
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("SuitesTest\\TVASuite.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
```

And this is what I have inside my xml:

```
<suite name="TVA Suite">
<parameter name="app" value="tva" />
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="app.common.listeners.TestListener" />
    <listener class-name="app.common.listeners.AnnotationTransformer"/>
</listeners>
<test name="TVA Test">
    <classes>
        <class name="app.tva.tests.LoginTest" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
    List<String> testFilesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    testFilesList.add("./testng.xml"); //test suite resides in the working directory's root folder
    **testng.setTestSuites(testFilesList);** //you can addd multiple suites either here by adding multiple files or include all suites needed in the testng.xml file 
    testng.setUseDefaultListeners(false);
    testng.addListener(htmlRep); 
    testng.run();
```